# Converting enum to class, but not sure what pattern to use?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

I'm relatively new to Objective-C and I have an enum with a corresponding array of string descriptions:

```
typedef enum {
    kCoverage = 0,
    kSingulation,
    kPopulation,
    kDownforce,
} MapTileType;

static NSString* const kMapTileTypeString[] = {
    [kCoverage] = @"Coverage",
    [kSingulation] = @"Singulation",
    [kPopulation] = @"Population",
    [kDownforce] = @"Downforce",
};
```

I'm discovering that I actually need to define behavior for the "type" of map tile.  For instance, I have a tile rendering behavior that applies to a specific type of map tile.

```
static RenderingStrategy* const kMapTileTypeRenderingStrategy[] = {
    [kCoverage] = ...,
    [kSingulation] = ...,
    ...
};
```

I'm wondering if all of this stuff would be better suited for a class definition for encapsulation purposes.  Or would I just use a factory method that receives a `MapTileType` and returns a `RenderingStrategy`?

I was thinking that I could also perhaps just use a delegate:

```
@protocol MapTileDelegate <NSObject>
-(NSString*)description;
-(void)renderBlahBlah...;
@end
```

Can somebody help break my analysis paralysis?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, there are two approaches that sound like they might make sense:

1. Turn the MapTileTypes into subclasses of MapTile that implement the custom behavior you're looking for.
2. Create a MapTileBehavior class or something along those lines and have instances of that class take the place of your MapTileTypes values.